# Limit to 1 page all document sent to printer

Tags: printing, registry, driver

I have a Seiko SLP 620 printer, and a Hundegger K2 program (that controls a Hundegger K2 machine) that send labels to the printer. The problem is that the program print the good label, but print a blank label after the good one each time.

The program is incredibly old, and only accept specific printer settings, and each time I try to change those settings, they set back to default (so the solution can't be with print settings)

The program detect a default paper format, and print the label with this format (it's not the good format). I tried to change in print setting the default paper format, but, as I said, the program change it to is own default setting. I tried to change the available paper format in registry for the driver, but nothing changed for the program. I tried every driver available for this printer, but it did not work.

My question is: How can I limit the number of pages that are sent to the printer so that it always prints only 1 page, even if the program ask for 2 ?

*Please, if my question is not good, help me correct it. I want to be better, and only vote down will not help me... Comment and my next question will include your help :)*

Answer (score 0):

Is this program "old enough" that maybe it expected to run in MS-DOS? If it's running (say) under Windows now, then it is required to "spool" the output to Windows for actual printing ... and Windows can therefore exert *its* influence, too.

Windows sees all program output as a so-called "metafile" which it then "renders" onto the printed page, using settings such as paper-size, printable margins and so-forth, all of which the originating program might know nothing of and can't control. "Back in the days of DOS," this intermediate layer of software didn't exist.

So, maybe the *slightest* "tweak" of a paper-margin setting might do the trick. (Or even, if you can, telling Windows to use "legal size" paper for its calculations, when in fact a smaller piece of paper or label-stock is what's in the machine.) You're basically going to have to "fiddle with whatever settings you can find," until you find what works.  **:-/**

Comment: I discovered that the program takes a specific setting in the printer's driver. I tried the 2 pages per label option, and yes, it prints the 2 pages on the same label (so I do have a little control on the print settings). But the problem remains, It always prints 2 pages, for every settings possible on the printer. When the printer found that the label sent by the program is too big for 1 page, it prints 2 pages, plus 1 blank after, always. Is it possible to force the driver to always print only the 1st page ? Or remove some lines before sending it to the driver ?

Comment: "Who the heck *knows?"* Maybe the customer just has to live with "that extra page." (And, if nothing is actually being *printed* on it, s/he can just put it back in the bin ... "none the worse for wear.") Yeah, sometimes that's just the way that these things wind up in real life ... **:-/**

Comment: The problem is that the pages are stickers on a roll. In order to put them back in the printer, I need to wait until all the roll is used, and put it back in the same order. This is a problem because it's twice the cost if we trash them, and a real pain if we want to reuse the blank ones (yeah, the second page is always blank)

Comment: *"Keep looking ... keep looking ..."* (What else can I say?) I had **exactly** the same problem, years ago now, and I candidly confess that ... "I never did completely solve it."  **:-/**

Comment: Finally, I did not solve the problem either. After hours of research with drivers and virtual printers and redirection ports, I decided to let this go, and I did another application that prints exactly what I need, on only one page...

Comment: *That* doesn't surprise me too much. However, the bottom line is: "you found a way to do it!"  **:-D**