# How to create a fake printer driver to pass print file to real printer

Tags: printing, driver

I want to know how to make an application that will emulate a printer with a specific name ("SLP Pro" in my case), and with only ony type of paper ("SLP-SRL Shipping(54x101mm)" in my case).

My goal is to receive print files (I have no idea what type they are, they are from a very old program), and redirect them to a label printer. The problem is that I want my application to only redirect the first page, and nothing else, from the original print file.

My question is following this one: [Limit to 1 page all document sent to printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229157/limit-to-1-page-all-document-sent-to-printer)
(It's the same problem as described there, only I have tried all possibilities I had with my current driver for my label printer)

I know there is http://www.colorpilot.com/emfprinterpilot.html and [www.printerplusplus.com](http://www.printerplusplus.com/), but I really don't know how to use them. Can those solutions handle print files that are not from known application like Word ? (The first one seem to take the file with the extention and redirect it, I really want to take the print file and crop it to only one page)

If my question is too vague, can you please tell me where I can find the good information ? I've found many things that to things a bit like I want to do, but they where not applicable to my situation, and I really don't know where to search now...

Comment: This question is a bit out of scope for stackoverflow - there's no answer that will fit in a few pages of text that will reasonably explain how to write a printer driver.

Comment: I see... Sorry for the bad question... On the meta side, how this kind of question should be asked on Stackoverflow? Should I ask for link to tutorials ? How can I change the question to have at least a bit of help and know where to do more search on the subject ?